# When in doubt between -chan and -kun what to choose?

Tags: honorifics

I want to call one of my friend, who is not Japanese, by adding -chan or -kun to his name. The friend is a student of Japanese as myself from the same group. A male, not homosexual. I think he's about the same age as myself. We are friends but not extremely close friends, but friends during the classes and sometime chat outside.
Based on that do I use -chan or -kun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kun! chan is very cutesy.  Kun is more usable among colleagues/fellow scholars.